# Do variables that reference an object that is stored in a Session variable get collect by GC?

Tags: c#, memory-management, garbage-collection

I'm not all that familiar with how garbage collection works and what causes memory leaks. But I'm at the point were I'm becoming concerned about it and want to write more efficient code. So the project I'm working on, which is an Asp.Net web application, has an instance of a custom DataCriteria being created when a Session starts in the global.asax and is then stored in a Session variable. This custom DataCriteria is what we are using to communicate with the database for the CRUD methods.

First question is, say we have a Person class, and in this Person class there is a DataCriteria field which is set to the Session variable instance of the DataCriteria. Since an instance of Person holds a reference to an instance of the DataCriteria that will not get disposed of till Session ends, will that instance of Person be able to be collected. Or will every instance of Person not be disposed of till that Session ends.

Second question is more general, but same issue. Basically I'm wondering will a variable that is declared in a method that references the Session variable instance of the DataCriteria be able to be collected by the GC? Or will it too stay till the Session ends?

I thank you for all the advise you can give me here. And if you know of any good reads for understanding Garbage Collection and avoiding memory leaks I would love to hear about them too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The references held by an object do not affect its availability for garbage collection.  However, the inverse is not true.  For example, let's say an instance A has a field that holds an instance B.  A will become available for garbage collection as soon as nothing else references it, even if B is static or otherwise "long lived".  However, B will not become available for garbage collection *at least* until A becomes available for garbage collection.

Where things can get a bit odd is where references are not too obvious.  For example, an instance C becomes referenced by an instance D when C subscribes to an event exposed by D.  This means that, if D is long-lived, C will not become available for garbage collection before D unless it unsubscribes from the event.  References held via events and other delegates actually account for most of the "memory" leaks in .NET applications.  (Properly speaking, these aren't really memory leaks since there is no actual failure to clean up memory that is not used by actual object instances.)

Comment: Thank you, that is a great answer. I was actually going to ask about event handlers. So what about if instance C subscribes to it's own events? Should you unsubscribe these in a Dispose methods. Or is that just not needed? Are just subscriptions to other reference events needed to be handled in the Dispose method?

Comment: Self-references will not keep an object alive.  (Similarly, references between a set of instances that are not referenced by anything else will not keep any of them alive either.)  This means that there is no need to unsubscribe from one's own events.  (That said, subscription to self events is a rather expensive approach to triggering actions within an instance.)  Within an object's Dispose method, it should only be necessary to clear its own events and unsubscribe from events on other objects.

Comment: So if my Person class inherits another class that implements the INotifyPropertyChanged interface. And the Person instance has a handler for the PropertyChanged event. Is that a handler that I should unsubscribe from in the Dispose.  I guess I need an actual example to clearly understand it.

Comment: A Person instance does not need to unsubscribe from its own PropertyChanged event, regardless of whether that event is declared in Person or one of its base classes. However, if the Person class has a Child property of type Person, and a Person instance subscribes to an event on its Child, and the Child instance might outlive the parent instance, the parent instance should unsubscribe from the Child event during disposition.

Comment: Ok that makes sense. I appreciate the explanation. Now I guess I better go remove some unneeded code. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Object references constitute a directed graph - object A references object B. Until A is collected, B cannot be.

Session is just another object that references stuff - it is object A referencing your object B in this case.

So in your case, just becuase Person references something also stored in Session does not mean Person stays around until Session goes away. unless Session references your Person, their lifetimes are not linked.

Now what you DO have to watch out for is what else your DataCriteria references. If it holds database connections or other objects, they will live as long as the Session does.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. You guys have been very helpful with this. I would mark yours as the answer as well, but she included that event handler portion. But none the less, thank you so much for clarifying this.